# Decimal "constant" for lat and long in miles

Tags: geospatial

Understanding that it would only be an estimate...

How what decimal constant would be able to be used to find a point X Miles away from a point in latitude and longitude to facilitate creating a lat long bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such simple constant. As you go farther north, the "walking distance" between lines of longitude becomes smaller and smaller. If you were right next to the north pole, you could walk in a circle around it, covering almost no distance at all, and yet you'd still have touched every line of longtiude.

What you need is the [great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) between two points on a sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do. You want a create a bounding box based on distance from a point? Are you looking for a way to calculate new lat/long from given lat/long using a distance in miles?

You can use the manhattan function to get an approximation of distance (realizing that lat/long are based on a spheroid approximating the earth, and truly calculating this requires more math), calculating x and y values with a forumla to follow

Manhattan function:

```
sqrt(x*x + y*y)
```

X and Y from Lat/Long:

```
x = 69.1 * (lat2 - lat1)
y = 53 * (lon2 - lon1)
```

Still, that method is pretty error-prone.

There's the great circle distance formula too, gotta use some trig for it, but it's probably worth it since you can get pretty good error in approximation depending upon what part of the spheroid (e.g. the lat/long) you start at.

Check out this page:

http://www.meridianworlddata.com/Distance-Calculation.asp

Comment: PS: People in Antarctica have a "race around the world" every year in which they run through all 24 time zones, at a distance of about half a kilometer from the south pole. That's an example of why you can't use a constant, since the entire race is maybe a km or two, but near the equator it's some 4000km i beleive.

Comment: I can assume that I won't be deailing with the poles. This is for finding the distance between two points.  I have a single point and a radius and want to get a bounding box to surround that area... My Users at this point won't care if it actually returns something 5.7 miles when they asked for 5 (at this point)

Comment: If the radius is small,absolute error will also be small with above functions. I would use that. You CANNOT have a constant to calculate this... unless, perhaps, you are working with a very small geographical area. Still, I think you will see a lot of distortion/error between southern-most and northern-most points in your area, even if small. I'm not sure what GIS system you may be using, but if you have access to (and skills to use) PostGIS and PostGreSQL (opensource), you can do queries and have the DB figure it all out. Might be overkill for you. 

Radius Query: http://tinyurl.com/35poqxr